# Captcha without rewriting image in PHP?

Tags: php, captcha

I am looking for a way, how to protect my form against spam bots. I am not a big fan of image captcha, because for user is it another "unnecessary" work.

Bot fill out all inputs and send form. My clue was make a hidden input and after sending form test, if the hidden input is still empty. If does -> good, human. If doesn't -> bot.

How much perspective and able-to-work is this solution? What do you think?

Comment: This is known as a honeypot (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_%28computing%29)

Comment: I think the bots nowadays are smart enough to read the hidden attribute and skip it :)

Comment: You could also add a hidden field and when the page loads use javascript to fill in in with 'safe'. But that makes people without javascript enabled unable to submit the form too! I quite like the PHP website captcha e.g. "max of 4 and 5"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a pretty standard measure for preventing SPAM. I don't have any figures on how effective it is. But I would imagine that not very much.